# Should tabstat and centile give different results for percentiles?

Tags: stata

```
.  sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)
. centile price, centile(25 75)

                                                   -- Binom. Interp. --
    Variable |       Obs  Percentile    Centile        [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
       price |        74         25        4193        4009.467    4501.838
             |                   75        6378        5798.432      9691.6

. tabstat price, stat(p25 p75)

    variable |       p25       p75
-------------+--------------------
       price |      4195      6342
```

When making calculations by hand, my answers agree with the `centile` command, and disagree with the `tabstat` command (bonus: they also disagree with the `sum , detail` command).

Where is this discrepancy (25th percentile: 4193 vs 4195, and 75th percentile: 6378 vs 6342) coming from?

I am using Stata 15.1 for Unix.

Comment: In essence, the commands use different estimation methods, so small differences aren't surprising. For the detail, see the Methods and formulas sections of the Manual for `summarize` and  `centile`.